# How to reduce code size for checkbox list in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like you can see with my code, I'm totally a beginner in JavaScript, jQuery and globally in programming language.

I search to keep a checkbox list with less line of code.

Can you help me?

```
$('#customSwitch1').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        $("#LoginModal1").modal();
    }
});
$('#customSwitch2').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        $("#LoginModal2").modal();
    }
});
$('#customSwitch3').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        $("#LoginModal3").modal();
    }
});
$('#customSwitch4').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        $("#LoginModal4").modal();
    }
});
```

Comment: "_to keep a checkbox list with less line fo code._" Not getting what you mean here. What is your expected output?

Comment: he means to refine the code @palaѕн

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal? I think to open modal you need to call `.modal('show');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
const mapObj = {
    'customSwitch1': 'LoginModal1',
    'customSwitch2': 'LoginModal2',
    'customSwitch3': 'LoginModal3',
    'customSwitch4': 'LoginModal4'
}

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            $("#" + mapObj[$(e.target).attr('id')]).modal();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The technique you're looking for is call Don't Repeat Yourself, or DRY. To dry this up you can use common classes along with `data` attributes to store the custom metadata in each element. Something like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="customSwitch" data-target="#LoginModal1" />    
<input type="checkbox" class="customSwitch" data-target="#LoginModal2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="customSwitch" data-target="#LoginModal3" />
```

```js
$('.customSwitch').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $($(this).data('target')).modal();
});
```

Comment: Why `.data()`? We only need the content of `data-target` to be a string hence the good ol' `.getAttribute()` would yield the same result: `$(this.getAttribute("data-target")).modal()`

Comment: True, but then there's not enough jQuery :) If you wanted to do it natively I'd suggest `this.dataset.target` to avoid accessing the DOM again.

Answer (score 0):

You can group all checkboxes in one event listener, parse the last character of the id, and append it to the corresponding modal id as follows:

```
$('#customSwitch1, #customSwitch2, #customSwitch3, #customSwitch4').on('change', function(e) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
           let id = e.target.id;
           let modalId = id.match(/\d+/);
           $(`#LoginModal${modalId[0]}`).modal();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this: `[id^="customSwitch"]` selects all elements with an `id` that starts with "customSwitch".

```
 $('[id^="customSwitch"]').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      selected = $(this).attr("id").substr(12);
      $("#LoginModal" + selected).modal();
    }
 });
```